# What is an efficient and ergonomic way to sort the keys of a map?

Tags: erlang

How can I put the keys of a Map in sorted order?
I tried this, but it doesn't seem memory-efficient, as there are three copies of the key set:

```
sort_map(In) -> sort_map(In, lists:sort(maps:keys(In))).
sort_map(In, Keys) ->
    lists:foldl(
        fun (Key, Out) -> Out#{Key => maps:get(Key, In)} end,
        #{},
        Keys
    ).
```

### Update

This question doesn't make sense: keys in a `Map` are not guaranteed to be kept in insertion order, as [pointed out by @JoseM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986521/2482570). I'd mis-read something in the [Maps EEP](http://erlang.org/eeps/eep-0043.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps in Erlang have no 'publicly' defined order since the concept of a "sorted map" has little meaning. Obviously, internally the keys have an order, but you can do little to influence it by changing the order of the insertions (maps are implementing with a Hash Array-Mapped Trie when they have more than 32 elements, you have a really interesting article [here](https://medium.com/@jlouis666/breaking-erlang-maps-1-31952b8729e6)).

Regarding memory efficiency, large Erlang terms are references, so although the key set is copied, it's not a deep copy for the large Keys. (Unless you send them to other process - large binaries are reference-counted)

I'm unsure about what you're trying to achieve here.
You may want to have a look at [orddicts](https://erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html) (although they are not implemented natively), or implement your own structure.

Recently I had to use a `{map(K => _), queue(K)}` for a queue where elements could disappear in the middle of the queue. I use the map to track which elements are in the queue and check the presence of an element every `pop()`. Maybe you can use a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, it's faster to first convert the map to a list and then sort the list:

```
sort_map(In) ->
    lists:keysort(1, maps:to_list(In)).
```

Using a map of 235886 string keys, each key having a string value the same as the key, your solution took an average of 0.918 seconds across 100 runs, whereas the solution above averaged 0.573 seconds. With a map of the same size but with binary keys and values, the averages were 0.494 seconds and 0.332 seconds respectively.